Get the value two rows above the XLOOKUP results
  | A  |        B        | C |    D    |
--|----|-----------------|---|---------|---
1 |    |Brand A          |   | Criteria|
2 |    |Production Line1 |   |   P2    |
3 | P1 |      500        |   |         |
4 | P1 |      100        |   | Result  |
5 | P1 |      800        |   | Brand B |
6 |    |                 |   |         |
7 |    |Brand B          |   |         | 
8 |    |Production Line1 |   |         |
9 | P2 |      700        |   |         |
10| P2 |      300        |   |         |
11|    |                 |   |         |
12|    |Brand C          |   |         |
13|    |Production Line2 |   |         |
14| P3 |      200        |   |         |
15| P3 |      500        |   |         |
16| P3 |      800        |   |         |
17| P3 |      300        |   |         |
18|    |                 |   |         |


In Cell D5 I want to extract the brand based on the criteria in Cell D2.  So far I have been able to implement this XLOOKUP:
=XLOOKUP(D2,A1:A18,B1:B18,NA(),0)

The result of this XLOOKUP is 700. 
However, I need to modify the XLOOKUP so it always takes the value in the cell two rows above the results. 
In the example Cell B7 (Brand B)
Do you have any idea how to do this?

=OFFSET(XLOOKUP(D2,A1:A18,B1:B18,NA(),0),-2,0)

Just offset your range, without actually using OFFSET() since it's volatile:
=XLOOKUP(D2,A3:A20,B1:B18,NA())

Also, XLOOKUP() will return an exact match by default.

I answered the same and deleted, but no need to declare NA() either. That'll be the error in case the search value is not present.
